# Best way to join string with transform in a standard way

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

I'm looking for the best way to join a container with transformation as a string. The old style, that I'm using looks like this:

```
std::string MyJoin(const std::vector<Foo>& foos) {
  std::string str;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < foos.size(); ++i) {
    if (i != 0) {
      str += ",";
    }
    str += Stringify(foos[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

This works well, and performance is ok, but I was wondering if there is an equally performant standard way. I tried Range-V3:

```
std::string MyJoin(const std::vector<Foo>& foos) {
  return foos | transform(Stringify) | cache1 | join(',') | to<std::string>;
}
```

It is a beautiful single liner, easy to read, but it was half performant from the old one. I tested with a million element of foos.

Am I doing something wrong? or the old way is the way to go? I'm wondering if there is a wonderful solution, that I couldn't find in other answers.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: "*[...] but it was half performant from the old one*" - please share your benchmark process. The compiler, flags fed to it, machine, exact data... Also, those features are still quite new and compilers are yet to find the best ways of optimising such code.

Comment: what's `cache1`?

Comment: @Caleth it [caches the most recent element](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1cache1__fn.html).